# Entity Framework and Postgresql: stored procedures

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using Entity Framework with postgresql. A common case is that I'd like to select a function result as a part of a query, like

```
SELECT t.id, func1(t.id) FROM table1 t WHERE...
```

The problem is, that I cannot import stored procedures to entity framework from postgresql. (I get a not supported exception when trying to import them.) As a workaround, I have views of form

```
id, func1(id)
```

However, this seems to be very slow when used in joins. An example of a slow query:

```
SELECT t.id, f.func_result
FROM table1 t
JOIN func_view f on f.id = t.id
WHERE t.id IN (...)
```

About 1000 times faster version, even with a correlating subquery:

```
SELECT t.id,(
    SELECT f.func_result
    FROM func_view f
    WHERE f.id = t.id
) FROM table1 t
WHERE t.id IN (...)
```

However, when I write this query in entity framework, it seems to use the first version. Is there a way to force EF to use a subquery? Or is there another more efficient workaround?